# Maths behind Unity rigidbody.AddForce

Tags: unity, physics, mathematics, rigidbody

I've tried to understand the Maths behind `AddForce`, as to reproduce it using `rigidbody.velocity +=`.

Based on the formulas provided by PhysX documentation for [AddForce](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/physx/apireference/files/structPxForceMode.html#adaaafefe0478d829b816154c676e5459f25946973fec4c78991859e8bf76376), we have:

```
eFORCE            parameter has unit of mass * distance/ time^2, i.e. a force
eIMPULSE          parameter has unit of mass * distance /time
eVELOCITY_CHANGE  parameter has unit of distance / time, i.e. the effect is mass independent: a velocity change.
eACCELERATION     parameter has unit of distance/ time^2, i.e. an acceleration. It gets treated just like a force except the mass is not divided out before integration.
```

I tried to convert these formulas above to a `rigidbody.velocity +=` syntax, but I am unable to get the Maths right.

Here is what I got working:

```cs
float force = 3f;
public void FixedUpdate() {
  // Same as r.AddForce(force, ForceMode.Force)
  Vector2 distance = (force / r.mass) * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
  r.velocity += distance;
}
```

```cs
float force = 3f;
public void FixedUpdate() {
  // Same as r.AddForce(force, ForceMode.Impulse)
  Vector2 distance = (force / r.mass);
  r.velocity += distance;
}
```

I tested both of them, by superposing two rigidbodies, one using `AddForce`, while the other used `r.velocity+=`. So far, it seem my convertion is correct as they move exactly the same.

As for the Maths I am not getting right, here is what I came with:

```
eFORCE = mass * distance/ time^2
eFORCE / mass = distance/ time^2
(eFORCE / mass) * time^2 = distance
```

```
distance = (eFORCE / mass) * time^2
```

Same as ?

```
Vector2 distance = (force / r.mass) * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
```

That woud mean `time^2` is equal to `Time.fixedDeltaTime`.

Then let's do the same for `ForceMode.Impulse`:

```
eIMPULSE = mass * distance /time
eIMPULSE / mass = distance / time
(eIMPULSE / mass) * time = distance
```

Meaning `time` is `Mathf.Sqrt(Time.fixedDeltaTime)` ?
Well, as you guessed, on the terrain this doesn't check out.

I like to get the Maths right, how do I get to the **result c# code I have shown** (that seem correct) starting from the **PhysX documentation** ?

Comment: Why are you taking the square root instead of squaring? `time^2` is equivalent to `time*time`, so moving that to the delta version, wouldn't it be `Time.fixedDeltaTime * Time.fixedDeltaTime`?

Comment: @Pikalek This is part of the thing bothering me. `time^2` should be `Time.fixedDeltaTime * Time.fixedDeltaTime` for `ForceMode.Force`, but the **formula that is working when testing** is `distance = (force / r.mass) * Time.fixedDeltaTime`, not `distance = (force / r.mass) * Time.fixedDeltaTime * Time.fixedDeltaTime`. I made the assumption `time^2` is somehow equivalent to `Time.fixedDeltaTime`. But this assumption is wrong when testing that on `ForceMode.Impulse`.